# Connect an directory index to another directory index

Tags: php, css, yii, cpanel, directoryindex

I'm trying to call my index.php on my cPanel, however since my hosting service only allows up to 1 sublevel of directory, I have to bring up my index.php.

I'm using Yii framework, and since it's my first application. I dont know how to link it. I also just continued the application from another developer, it's making me confused on how to change or place my index.php

Is it possible to create an index.php to call another index.php, since the current index.php, still has to run the yii framework? I dont want to change the directory paths since there's just too many paths to change.

UPDATE:

Found out I was inputting the wrong path, I've got it to show the page, but now it does not load any of the images/css. What's seems to be the problem now?

Answer (score 2):

I might be asking a dumb question, but have you tried a PHP Include? This won't affect paths or anything, but the code from the included index.php will be used in the first page...

```
<?PHP
   include_once('directory/index2.php');
?>
```

Comment: Yeah I did try it, but seems to me that it doesn't run the yii framework on the other index.php